# slowly scroll to top not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I made a this function for scrolling to top in javascript :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function go()
{
     $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Now when I want to click the specific image for scrolling to top not working :

```
<p><a href="JavaScript:go()"><img src="1.jpg" width="418" height="128" border="0" /></p></a>
```

It doesn't work. How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `onclick="go();"` instead of `href="JavaScript:go()"`

Comment: @JiFus can you post the answer, cause it's not working.

Comment: Did you reference the jQuery script? That works on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you asked for an answer, here you go:

I made a JSFiddle to demonstrate it works.

instead of using `onclick="go()"` I decided to use `.on("click", function(){})` because JSFiddle works with POST.

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/3mruenhh/2/).

jQuery used:

```
$("#go").on("click", function() {
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
});
```

HTML used:

```
<p>The lazy dog jumps over the big brown fox</p>
<p>The lazy dog jumps over the big brown fox</p> // Obviously, this is dummy content.
<img style="width: 100px;" src="http://animalia-life.com/data_images/dog/dog4.jpg" id="go" />
```

Comment: The problem is i'm using image and want to use HREF for changing mouse icon and also your code won't work with image.

Comment: I updated my answer to your needs. If you click the link now you will see: A picture, and the cursor being a pointer (css).

Comment: No. It won't do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71900/discussion-between-aliboy38-and-jifus).

Answer (score 1):

Give `void(0);` for href tag to prevent the default behavior. The use `onclick` attribute to call the js function.

```
<p><a href="void(0);" onclick="go();"><img src="1.jpg" width="418" height="128" border="0" /></p></a>
```

Comment: not working. it tries to call void(0) and won't work. Goes to this page : file:///C:/Users/Computer/Desktop/void(0);

Comment: @JiFus I know. I don't want to go any page. Just want slowly go to top.